# Allow Apostrophe, a dot, ampersand, digit and Characters in Regex C#

Tags: c#, ios, regex, xamarin.forms

I am using the following RegEx:

```
public const string SpecialCharRegex = @"^[A-Za-z0-9\s\(\)\.\&\-',`]+$";
```

I am using this to validate a field in my iOS App on an iPhone.

I like to match all characters in this class. However, I have a problem with the typographical smart/curly apostrophes.

Example:

```
My name is AB'c
```

is okay, but it will throw an error if this is entered on an iPhone.

It turns out that the iOS keyboard doesn’t put in an apostrophe ‘ (char 39) but instead, it is a Unicode ‘smart’ left quote (char 8216). How to adjust the pattern to match smart quotes too?

Comment: Are you saying that the regex throws an exception? Please tell us exactly what exception, both the name of the exception and the message. Please also show us code which will throw the exception when we compile it and run it.

Comment: Exeception means I am just checking whether the details entered is valid or not... E.g. O’Zombila is a valid name but my regex throws me a not a match

Comment: Please state unambiguously whether your code is actually throwing an actual exception which is a sublcass of `System.Exception`, or whether you just use the word "throw" as an all-purpose adjective, e.g. "I throw my car home after work".

Answer (score 2):

There are a many [quotation mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark) characters out there.

I suppose you want to catch those as well:

> U+2018: LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
>   U+2019: RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
>   U+201C: LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
>   U+201D: RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK

Add them like this so your [character class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions): `\uFFFF` or `\xFF` (see [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/nonprint.html))

```
string SpecialCharRegex = @"^[A-Za-z0-9\s\(\)\.\&\-',`\u2018\u2019\u201C\u201D]+$";
```

Comment: @EdPlunkett Have you tested this? Works on my end: https://ideone.com/M1P8sJ

Comment: Sorry, low IQ day over here. You're correct, the regex parser will handle \u2018 just as well as the C# compiler would.